# Using ngroute to redirect unauthorized users in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am making a web app using Angular for front-end.
If user whose role is teacher trying to access applicant's portal, I want to block them by showing 404.html template. I do not want to redirect the users to `www.example.com/404` but rather just let them stay at where they are at `www.example.com/teacher` but render 404.html template.

I am not sure how I can achieve this using ngroute. Here is the code what I have in app.js:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 'CookieProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, CookieProvider) {
            var cookieData = CookieProvider.$get().getCookieData();

$routeProvider.when('/applicant', {
            templateUrl: '/front-end/public/views/Prescreening/review.html',
            controller: 'ReviewCtrl',
            resolve:{
                "check":function($location, CookieService) {
                            var cookieData = CookieService.get();
                            if(cookieData["user_role"] == 'teacher'){
                                $location.path('/404')
                            }
                }
            }
        }).when('/404', {
            templateUrl: '/404.html'
        }).otherwise({
            templateUrl: '/404.html'
  });
  }]);
```

How can I render 404.thml without redirecting the user to `/404` ?

Comment: check out my answer @JoHksi.. I got it working in a plunker..

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a state like this.

```
.state('dashboard.users', {
    url: '/users/:isAdmin',
    templateUrl: 'modules/dashboard/templates/users.html',
    controller: 'usersController',
})
```

Try this.

```
angular.module(...)
    .config( ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {...}] )
    .run(function($rootScope, $location) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
            // You can pass the user role to the params 
            // of the state and you will see that on the 
            // toParams call callback ex. {isAdmin:false}
            if(!toParams.isAmin){
                toState.templateUrl = "modules/404/templates/404.html";
            }
        });
    })
})
```

**UPDATE**

The callback `toState` actually contains the following

1. `url` = url of the current state ex. `/user`
2. `templateUrl` = path to the template ex. `path/to/something.html`
3. `controller` = the controller name of the state ex. `usersController`
4. `name` = the state name ex. `dashboard.user`

When this line gets executed `toState.templateUrl = "modules/404/templates/404.html";` The current template of your state which falls under the `<div ui-view></div>` will have the `404.html` that you desire.

**IMPORTANT**

You must use `ui.router` and not `ngRouter` to make this implementation work.

Comment: wait, so how do I not direct users to 404.html but just render the template even in here?

Comment: Is there any way you can just do with ngroute? I just want to render different  template on certain condition

Answer (score 0):

After some efforts I got it working... Here are the different codes...

I have used bower so please replace with your paths..

Here is the plunk.. I got it working..
https://plnkr.co/edit/dK7n6PmhldJ1p0plWPp2?p=preview

index.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
        .when('/applicant', {
            template: 'Applicant!',
            controller: function($scope){
              alert("Applicant Controller");
            }
        })
        .when('/404', {
            templateUrl: '404'
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl : '404.html'
        });

}]);
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src = "index.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

404.html

```
<h1>404 page</h1>
```

Comment: I am trying to make a plunker... I will notify you when done... By that time you may ask me if you have any problem regarding my answer..